# What does it mean to be conformal?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I've read the definition several times but I'm having difficulty understanding what it really means. If anyone could explain it on a basic / intuitive level I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Which definition have you seen?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01Dp130VzAA

Comment: it means you talk the same way as everyone else and dress the same way as everyone else

Comment: @WillJagy You're a funny man, Will.

Comment: Angle-preserving.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What about length scaling ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: any isometry or uniform dilation is conformal, of course, but the converse is not true, so by defining *conformal* as *length-scaling* one should specify length-scaling *how*. I believe it is simpler to say that angles are preserved, to get a geometric grasp of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Of course the orientation of the angles must be preserved. The conjugate reverses orientation. Scaling means the infinitesimal length regardless of direction is changed by a constant, depending on the point, and given by the norm of the derivative at a point. This also implies that the function or its conjugate is analytic.